# Newbie python issue

Tags: python

I'm trying to write some code to drive a Sense Hat
'
I want to use an LED line to indicate the temperature, then scroll it up over time.
The sense.set_pixels function expects a list of 64 RGB lists, so I have to manipulate my line lists into this function.

The first iteration of the code works as I expect.

On the second iteration the 'line1' variable unexpectedly takes on the full 'pixels' array values.
I can't see how or where this happens?

Below is my debug code (with SenseHat dependencies removed)

Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Thanks

```
#from sense_hat import SenseHat
import time
import datetime
import os
import sys

#sense = SenseHat()
led_step = 1.0    # no. degrees for 1 led
tmin = 21.0       # temp of left most led
tmax = tmin + (8 * led_step)

R = [255, 0, 0]  # Red
G = [0, 255, 0]  # Green
B = [0, 0, 255]  # Blue
X = [0, 0, 0] # Off

line1 = [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
line2 = [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
line3 = [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
line4 = [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
line5 = [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
line6 = [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
line7 = [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]
line8 = [X, X, X, X, X, X, X, X]

def getCPUtemperature():
#    res = os.popen('vcgencmd measure_temp').readline()
#    return(res.replace("temp=","").replace("'C\n",""))
     return "48.7"

def print_env():
#def print_env(sh):
#    tp = sense.get_temperature_from_pressure()
#    th = sense.get_temperature_from_humidity()
    tp = 32.9
    th = 33.4
    tc_s = getCPUtemperature()
    tc = float(tc_s)
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    nowstr = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

    tp = round(tp, 1)
    th = round(th, 1)

    print("%s TempH = %s, TempP = %s, TempCPU = %s" % (nowstr, th, tp, tc),end="\r")
    return [tp, tc]

try:
    for i in range(0,8):
        print()
    while True:
#        temp_l = print_env(sense)
        temp_l = print_env()
        print()
        temp = temp_l[0] - ((temp_l[1] - temp_l[0])/2)   # adjust ambient via cpu temp
        if (temp >= tmax):
            print("Temperature out of range: %s" % (temp))
            temp = tmax - stept
        if (temp < tmin):
            print("Temperature out of range: %s" % (temp))
            temp = tmin
        grn_led = int((temp - tmin) // led_step) # identify which led is current temp
        line = [B]*grn_led + [G] + [R]*(7-grn_led) # blue to left, red to right
        print("line", line)
        print()
        print("line8",line8)
        print("line7",line7)
        print("line6",line6)
        print("line5",line5)
        print("line4",line4)
        print("line3",line3)
        print("line2",line2)
        print("line1",line1)
        print()
        line8 = line7
        line7 = line6
        line6 = line5
        line5 = line4
        line4 = line3
        line3 = line2
        line2 = line1
        line1 = line

        print("line8",line8)
        print("line7",line7)
        print("line6",line6)
        print("line5",line5)
        print("line4",line4)
        print("line3",line3)
        print("line2",line2)
        print("line1",line1)
        print()
        print("line", line)
        print()

        pixels = line1
        pixels.extend(line2)
        pixels.extend(line3)
        pixels.extend(line4)
        pixels.extend(line5)
        pixels.extend(line6)
        pixels.extend(line7)
        pixels.extend(line8)

        print("pixels",pixels)
        print()
#        sense.set_pixels(pixels)       
        time.sleep(5)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting ...')
#    sense.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Paolo Moretti's explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793872/variable-assignment-and-modification-in-python).

I think that when you assign `line1` to `pixels`, then extend `pixels`, you're running up against Python's expected behaviour. Both variables point to the same list in memory, rather than `pixels` being an independent copy. To make it work I think you'll need to explicitly copy the `list1` variable:

```
pixels = list(list1)
pixels.extend(line2)
pixels.extend(line3)
pixels.extend(line4)
...
```